# Git and Laravel issue on VPS

Tags: git, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, laravel-5.1

I have a lot of non-laravel websites that deployed into amazon ec2 vps with git as the project uploader from localhost to the live server. I was following an instruction from http://devoncmather.com/setting-aws-ec2-instance-lamp-git/ to install git and connecting between repository folder and the live site folder. Once i pushed an update from my localhost to git remote server (which is installed on my vps), it's successfully updated as well on the live site folder.

Otherwise, it's not working on my laravel project. Once i pushed into git remote server, it's only updated inside the repository but NOT IN THE LIVE SITE FOLDER. How to solve this? i can't find a proper answer on Stack Overflow, maybe someone out there can help me?

Thank you

Comment: You would need to define what not working means? Are you seeing a 404 error, a 500 error or something else?

Comment: edit the `.gitignore` file to include laravel **vendor** directory. otherwise, you'll need to throw `composer update` in your server whenever you add or remove package(s).

Comment: hi @tix3, it's not working in a terms of data update. for example, i added new routes on Laravel. When i pushed into remote repository and i try to access the new live site, it supposed that new routes can be access. But unfortunately, it's not. And when my team mate try to pull the new repo, the new routes actually exists! hmmm.. quite confusing right.

Comment: hi @Tezla, yes i have tried that. but the thing is, the current version of live site it selves is not updated. So how can i supposed to do composer update when nothing new is applied. that's weird..

Comment: @UntagPranata, is it by any case you had several branch? like, one for development and one for production. anyway, try to connect directly to the vps, open the laravel's `route.php` manually in the vps - if it had different content than your new one, it caused by multi-branch. **note:** if your `route.php` in vps actually match with your local one, i suspect throwing `php artisan route:clear` could do something.

Comment: @Tezla after couple of hours strugling with this issue, i found the core problem. It's because the permission issue on all laravel folder. So the remote repo unable to rewrite anything on live repo folder. Do you have a trick to allow all folder writable on laravel project?

Comment: you could use cli, throw [chmod command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) however, as it in production server, i'm afraid there will be some other issue (does git and apache had the same user?). Hope someone will enlighten us :) as i myself always work on 'offline development server' first, then deploy.